# When I called log.Infof() from google.golang.org/appengine/log, Logging output "/logservice.Flush is not registered"

Tags: go, google-app-engine, logging

When I tried to output the log using `google.golang.org/appengine/log`, I got the following error in logging.

**internal.flushLog: Flush RPC: Call error 1: call /logservice.Flush is not registered**

Anyone know how to resolve this?

GAE/Go 1.16

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `google.golang.org/appengine/v2` for Go 1.12 or later.

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/services/access).